# .net cf 3.5 treeview Checkbox for the given node only

Tags: compact-framework, pocketpc

Treeview in .net cf 3.5 pocket pc app If we enable checkbox it will be displayed for all nodes, i want to show check box for childs of some nodes only. Is it possible ? i found some windows forms apps doing custom draw in drawnode event. But there is no drawnode event in .net cf treeview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct.  The CF TreeView is a simple wrapper around the native CE TreeView control, which does not support checkboxes.  You would have to create a fully custom control for this behavior.  It may be worth looking at third-party control vendors like Resco to see if they have anything (I don't know if they do or not).